# Error "collection was modified enumeration operation may not execute" when restoring database backup in Azure Data Studio

Tags: sql-server, azure, docker

I'm extremely new to databases so please bear with me.

I've set up local SQL Server running on a Docker container (using a Mac). I'm trying to restore SQL database using Azure Data Studio (v1.14.0) but it's not working.

I used the guide on [database.guide](https://database.guide/how-to-restore-a-sql-server-database-on-a-mac-using-azure-data-studio/) but keep getting errors. I have no clue what it means.

> Restore database failed: collection was modified; enumeration
>   operation may not execute

I have tried restoring .bak-file from a backup made on my school computer (used SQL Server Management Studio on a PC), tried restoring with the bak-file from Database.guide. I also made a backup from my current DB in Azure and tried restoring that one - didn't work either.

Comment: What was the actual SQL you ran?

Comment: @Larnu I didn't, I just used Azure Data Studio as UI, following the steps from [database.guide](https://database.guide/how-to-restore-a-sql-server-database-on-a-mac-using-azure-data-studio/) but I'm stuck at step 6.

Comment: That still runs SQL. Both SSMS and ADS have a Script button. Show us the script.

Comment: @Larnu I'm not sure how to do that, I started using ADS two days ago. When restoring backup I tried clicking the script-button (it immediately ran automated script I'm guessing) but got the same error. I don't know how to retrieve the actual SQL that ran when trying to restore the backup.

Comment: You press the Script button. It's literally labeled "Script".

Comment: @Larnu Yeah, that's what I did. Here's a ![screenshot](https://uploadpie.com/VR7L1N) of what it looks like after I click on the button literally labeled "Script".

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I finally got it to work! 
When restoring, in the files tab I ticked the box "Relocate all files" and specified the location to relocate the data and log files to /var/opt/mssql/data and that worked.

Comment: I wish I found this before I wasted hours on it. Upvote this thing!

Comment: Luckily, I searched and found this page before wasting hours. Thumbup!